# Changing default font color of the displayfield in EXTJS 4

Tags: extjs

I want to change the default font color of the displayfield Xtype in EXTJS 4. how is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their are few ways doing so:

1. setting styles (using `style`, `fieldStyle`, `labelStyle`...).
2. using css classes (using `cls`, `fieldBodyCls`...).
3. changing the theme (.scss) or .css.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Display

Answer (score 4):

You can use the html font tag to change the color of a displayfield.
For example:  `field.setValue('<font color="green">Hello</font>');`